# Remove item from .net hastable using value

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable

Is there a way without looping through the entire hashtable to remove key-value pairs with a specified value?

If not- is there a better type that I can use which will allow me to do this?

Here's a bit of background as to what I'm doing. I'm sure I'm overcomplicating and there's a better approach...

I have a list of key/values where the key is a column name in a "source" spreadsheet and the value is a field name in a "destination" system.

As I loop through the columns in the "source" and match the keys in the hashtable I can remove the pairs.

Once I am finished there may be columns in the "source" with no matching key in the hashtable. The user can override this by picking one of the remaining values.

This is where I then need to remove the that key/value from the hashtable.

Comment: Can't really make a suggestion without knowing how you're using it.  To answer your first question, 'no'

Comment: @MStodd i have added a description of what i'm doing. i'm sure it's probably idiotic :) thanks

Comment: @LeeTickett What you have described is exactly the scenario where a two-way lookup is entirely appropriate.  You'll want to build two dictionaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not.

If you want to do this it usually means one of two things

1. You have your keys and values reversed.  Make your values your keys and your keys your values.
2. You need two dictionaries.  One `Dictionary<T1, T2>` and one `Dictionary<T2,T1>`.  You'll need to populate it such that each pair is in both dictionaries and is consistent.  it also means that each value much be unique, rather than just the keys.  If your current values aren't unique, then you'd need a `Dictionary<T2, List<T1>>` or something similar, since each value might map to multiple keys.  Doing that would also make maintaining your structures...harder.  (Consider making a new `TwoWayDictionary` type if that's what you need.)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way without looping through the entire hashtable to remove key-value pairs with a specified value?

No. The point of a hashtable is that it's quick to look up by *key*, not value.

Note that you should generally be using `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` anyway, unless you're *really* using .NET 1.1.

> If not- is there a better type that I can use which will allow me to do this?

If you're going to have unique values as well as unique keys, you could just have two dictionaries, one each way. Then you can look up the key which corresponds to the relevant value, and remove from both dictionaries by key.

Answer (score -1):

The HashTable Class implements  IEnumerable so you can use query (LINQ) instead of Iterating

Comment: That's daft, and shows a complete lack of understanding of the mechanics of LINQ. What do you think is going on under the hood?

Comment: That means less code, but LINQ will, internally, iterate the structure.

Comment: @spender: you are right. LINQ would lazily iterate over the collection. I was suggesting an alternative to a foreach loop which will be more elegant. And you don't have to dish out insults when you disagree.

Comment: Apologies if you felt insulted. Not the intent at all. The question asked if they could avoid looping. As such, simply hiding the looping via a call to Linq does not IMO answer the question effectively.